# Language set to default after app close in android

Tags: android

i am making an multilingual application . i gave two options for language change . Language change is working but after user close app . it change back to default language .

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.hn:
            String languageToLoad = "hi";
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.eng:
            languageToLoad = "en"; // your language
            locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Intent in = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
            in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(in);
            break;

        default:

            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You need to save the user choice (in the Shared Preferences for example) and change the language accordingly each time the app is started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is partially based on [this post](https://proandroiddev.com/change-language-programmatically-at-runtime-on-android-5e6bc15c758).

Basically you need to create a custom Application class and call a method to change the language in both `onCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` as the language will otherwise be reset to default, for example, if the screen rotate.

**Custom Application**

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initLanguage();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        initLanguage();
    }

    private void initLanguage() {
        String ul = LanguageHelper.getUserLanguage(this);
        // if null the language doesn't need to be changed as the user has not chosen one.
        if (ul != null) {
            LanguageHelper.updateLanguage(this, ul);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to tell your app to use this custom class.
In the `AndroidManifest` under the `<application` add:

`android:name=".CustomApplication"`

**Language helper class**

```
public class LanguageHelper {

    private static final String GENERAL_STORAGE = "GENERAL_STORAGE";
    private static final String KEY_USER_LANGUAGE = "KEY_USER_LANGUAGE";

    /**
     * Update the app language
     *
     * @param language Language to switch to.
     */
    public static void updateLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        final Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
        cfg.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(cfg, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    /**
     * Store the language selected by the user.
     * /!\ SHOULD BE CALLED WHEN THE USER CHOOSE THE LANGUAGE
     */
    public static void storeUserLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        context.getSharedPreferences(GENERAL_STORAGE, MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putString(KEY_USER_LANGUAGE, language)
                .apply();
    }

    /**
     * @return The stored user language or null if not found.
     */
    public static String getUserLanguage(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(GENERAL_STORAGE, MODE_PRIVATE)
                .getString(KEY_USER_LANGUAGE, null);
    }
}
```

**In your Activity where the user choose the language**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String language;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.hn:
            language = "hi";
            LanguageHelper.storeUserLanguage(this, language);
            LanguageHelper.updateLanguage(this, language);

            // ... your code
            break;
        case R.id.eng:
            language = "en";
            LanguageHelper.storeUserLanguage(this, language);
            LanguageHelper.updateLanguage(this, language);

            // ... your code
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: how to call this method in on create .

Comment: Which method? You have everything you need above. `onCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` in `CustomApplication` call `initLanguage` which changes the app language based on what the user has selected in your Activity. It changes the language for the entire app.

Comment: The Application is the class which manage the entire app. It's automatically created and called by the system. This class is there by default even if you don't create one. In our case we just extend the default one in order to add new features.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sharedprefrences for this
save your selected language something like this

```
public void saveLanguage(String lang)
{
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
  Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
  editor.putString("lang", lang);
  editor.commit();
}
```

and each time your app will start fetch the language and apply it

```
public String fetchLanguage()
{
  SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
  return sharedpreferences.getString("lang", "NA");
 //NA is the default lang will be returned first time app started after choosing a language it wont . .
}
```

Comment: where to use it

Comment: saving function will be used in your above code where user selects language and fetch language function will be used in activity load method

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

**LanguageUtils**

```
public class LanguageUtils {

/**
 * change language
 *
 * @param context
 * @param language
 */
public static void shiftLanguage(Activity context, String language) {
    if (language.equals("en")) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferenceUtils.createSP(context, "en");
    } else {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.CHINESE);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = Locale.CHINESE;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        SharedPreferenceUtils.createSP(context, "zh");
    }
    context.recreate();
}

/**
 * app start setting language
 *
 * @param context
 * @param language
 */
public static void startLanguage(Context context, String language) {
    if (language.equals("zh")) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.CHINESE);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = Locale.CHINESE;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    } else {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
}
```

**Use it**

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.hn:
           String languageToLoad = "hi";
           LanguageUtils.shiftLanguage(this, languageToLoad);
           break;
      case R.id.eng:
           languageToLoad = "en"; // your language
           LanguageUtils.shiftLanguage(this, languageToLoad);
           break;

      default:
}
```

**And use it in Application**

When you restart app , it will set Language.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (TextUtils.equals(SharedPreferenceUtils.getLanguage(this), "en")) {
        LanguageUtils.startLanguage(getApplicationContext(), "en");
    } else {
        LanguageUtils.startLanguage(getApplicationContext(), "zh");
    }
}

}
```

**SharedPreferenceUtils**

```
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {

private static final String SP_NAME = "sp";
public static final String LANGUAGE = "language";


// create
public static boolean createSP(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(LANGUAGE, language);
    return editor.commit();
}


// get language
public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getString(LANGUAGE, "");
}

}
```